# Unable to place a Bitmap file on Desktop

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm creating a Drawing Application and for that i need to create a bitmap for a panel. My problem is when I get the desktop placement it gives me the Error of
" Field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.path'"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;



namespace Paint_AppLication
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private bool mouse_down = false;
    //My Problem
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    private Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(path + "\\" + "Bitmap.bmp");


    // Other Code Not my problem
    private Color col = Color.Black;
    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouse_down = true;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouse_down = false;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.X + ", " + e.Y;
        if (mouse_down == true)
        { 
            panel1.BackgroundImage = bit;
            bit.SetPixel(e.X, e.Y, col);

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
        col = colorDialog1.Color;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

 }

}
```

Comment: You have to put code in a method.  You can add it to the constructor. So change line to private Bitcmap bit = null;  The in the constructor add bit = new Bitmap(path + "\\" + "Bitmap.bmp");

Comment: Thanks but Visual studio is giving me an error every time I try to put Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(path + "\\" + "Bitmap.bmp") into a method or function saying "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected" As well as it needing another '}' iv added another '}' but it just multiplies the "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected" error

Answer (score 0):

**Because your field must be static:**

Initial code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
internal class MyClass1
{
    private readonly string _path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    private Bitmap _bitmap = new Bitmap(_path + "\\" + "Bitmap.bmp");
}
```

Fixed code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
internal class MyClass2
{
    private static readonly string _path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    private Bitmap _bitmap = new Bitmap(_path + "\\" + "Bitmap.bmp");
}
```

Even better, let `System.IO.Path` class build the path:

No more static field is required.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
internal class MyClass3
{
    private Bitmap _bitmap =
        new Bitmap(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Bitmap.bmp"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I'm getting "_bitmap does not exist in current context"